# Maximum function of continuous map from product space continuous

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be a topological spaces with $Y$ compact. Show that if $f  :X \times Y \to \Bbb R$ is continuous, then $g :X \to \Bbb R$ given by $g(x) = \max_{y \in Y} f(x,y)$ is also continuous.

If $f$ is continuous, then for any $U$ open in $\Bbb R$, the preimage $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in the product $X \times Y$.

We want to show that for $V \subset \Bbb R$ open $$g^{-1}(V)=\{x \in X \mid g(x)\in V\} = \{x\in X \mid \max_{y \in Y} f(x,y) \in V\}$$ is open.

Also because $Y$ is compact any open cover $\{C_i\}_{i \in I}$ has a finite subcover $\{C_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N}$.

I'm having some difficulties trying to show that $g^{-1}(V)$ is an open set. Do I need some properties of the maximum function here regarding compactness or is there some other way?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $X, Y$ are spaces, $Y\neq \emptyset$ is compact, $f:X\times Y\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, and let $g:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined as $g(x) := \max_{y\in Y} f(x, y)$.

If $a\in\mathbb{R}$ then $$g^{-1}[(a, \infty)] = \{x\in X : a < g(x)\} = \{x\in X : \exists_{y\in Y} a < f(x, y)\} = \bigcup_{y\in Y} \{x\in X : a < f(x, y)\}$$ which is open since $x\mapsto f(x, y)$ is continuous for every $y\in Y$.

On the other hand $$x\in g^{-1}[(-\infty, a)] \iff f[\{x\}\times Y]\subseteq (-\infty, a) \iff \{x\}\times Y\subseteq f^{-1}[(-\infty, a)].$$ If $x\in g^{-1}[(-\infty, a)]$, then $\{x\}\times Y\subseteq f^{-1}[(-\infty, a)]$ so from [tube lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tube_lemma) we can find neighbourhood of $x$, say $U\subseteq X$, such that $U\times Y\subseteq f^{-1}[(-\infty, a)]$, which means that $x\in U\subseteq g^{-1}[(-\infty, a)]$. This shows that $g^{-1}[(-\infty, a)]$ is open.

Since the open rays form a subbasis of $\mathbb{R}$, the function $g$ is continuous.